# pgAdmin portable without installation

Tags: pgadmin

Is there a possibility to run pgAdmin on Windows without any installation e.g. on a USB-drive?

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the outcome?

Comment: No,because I couldn´t find any download that provide all files that are needed

Answer (score 1):

I used the official Installer for Windows from here: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/
You can run the setup and install the pgadmin package for your current user only. Using this mode all the files are getting installed here: `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\pgAdmin 4\v6`

I was able to zip the contents of this directory, copied that ZIP to another machine, unpack it somewhere and just run the program `runtime\pgAdmin4.exe`

This worked for me on different machines.